# what is runtime.getruntime().exec("domain specific equivalent of cls") for windows 7

Tags: java, process, console-application, runtime.exec

I want to clear screen in my java application, after reading many questions and googling, I found the below code

```
runtime.getruntime().exec("cls")
```

or

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls");
```

but the above code doesn't work in windows 7. I am aware the "cls" script is domain specific, does anyone know what is the text I should use in windows 7. it will be really helpful, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to just write the ANSI escape sequences for 'Home' and 'Clear to EOS' to System.out.

Comment: @askappy I think I got, because the command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you are looking for an easy way to clear the screen.  You will have to use the newline hack or
use an ANSI enabled console.  Here is a little more difficult windows only method using JNA you or others reading this can consider.  This is an instructional example. Add error checking/handling/imports/includes as necessary. You must already know how to use JNA.  If you are new to JNA, this is a good 1st program for you to try.

```
//------------------------------------------
// Java2Win.class
//------------------------------------------
public interface Java2Win extends Library {
    Java2Win java2Win = (Java2Win)Native.loadLibrary("Java2Win64",Java2Win.class);
    void cls();
}
//------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------
// Java2Win.c (Java2Win.dll & Java2Win64.dll)
//------------------------------------------
JNIEXPORT void cls() {
   system("cls");
}
//------------------------------------------

//------------------------------------------
// Test
//------------------------------------------
public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
    final File file = new File("rootToDLL", "Java2Win64.dll");
    LibraryLoader.loadLibrary(file);
    System.out.println("-----some output");
    System.out.println("-----some output");
    System.out.println("-----some output");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Java2Win.java2Win.cls();
    System.out.println("-----cleared");
}
//------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `cls` is an internal command (something `cmd.exe` does itself rather than calling an executable program), you can do it with:

```
cmd /c cls
```

This works fine under Windows 7, assuming you're actually running a console-type application.

Comment: am gonna try this, but it looks like one of the many combinations I tried before.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls"); dint work got IO exception as usual.

Comment: @Radan You need to pass the parameters as a string array, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608944/adding-parameters-to-runtime-getruntime

Comment: it still doesn't work here with: ```String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "cls"}; Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);```

Comment: I can confirm that this didn't work for me either on Win7. I also tried: `String[] command = new String[] {"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "cls"}; Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` There is no error given, the line just looks like it's skipped.

Comment: @localhost: it doesn’t work, even when there are no errors, because when running sub-processes this way, the output of of the command gets redirected. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766/2711488)